# Can the href of a link be changed dynamically inside a twig temple in Symfony 2

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I've been working on a menu in my site for a while and I've been asking a lot of question about this menu. The idea is that my menu have a select with all my project and clicking my modify or delete button while do¸what it needs to do with the selected project.

So far, I found two possible ways to do this:

-Do a form with a select and three buttons (add, modify, delete)

-Do a link for each button and generate the select in twig with a loop

I think that the more logical option would be the second one, but the problem is that my link must send the id of the selected project.

Since twig generate the html for you, once it's generated, twig cannot it again, so I can't say to twig to change the link according to my selected project!

I know that there must be a way to solve this with Javascript, but, really, I would rather prefer using a form insteed, heaven if it would seems kind of weird in this situation, because the form already knows which project is selected and it's easy to use the controller to redirect on the next page for the modify button and delete the project.

If the link to the page would change, I would need to change my javascript  which is something that wouldn't happen with my oder sollution.

So, is there an other way to still make what I want with links without some javascript? If not, I'll just take my other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your form this way:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
->add('project', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array('1' => 'Project 1', '3' => 'Project 2')
))
->add('delete', 'submit', array('label' => 'Remove project'))
->add('update', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update project'))
->getForm();
```

`choices` can be even be an `entity` field type.

Then in controller:

```
$projectId = $form->get('project');

if ($form->get('delete')->isClicked()) {
// ...
} elseif ($form->get('update')->isClicked()){
// ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that's not what I'm locking for. I REALLY want a SELECT and 2 links. Your solution would create multiple button and links.

Comment: I've updated my answer, now there is one select and two buttons.

Comment: So, you think that I really should use a form insted of links? Because I already got a way to do it with a form, which is really similare to yours. The question was really more like if it was possible to do that with links, but after really thinking about it, it seems like the only is the form, but I want to be shure of that.

Comment: You can do it with links but you need javascript: $('.delbtn').click(function() {
   window.location = "delete/?id=" + id_retrieved_from_selected_option;
});

Comment: As I tought, I'll go with the form than, thanks for your help!